# Integrate returning complex values

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, complex

I am having trouble using mathematica to calculate some integrals

Namely this :

```
m44 = Assuming[
  0 < t < 1 && 0 < h < 0.1 && 
   t*Cos[θ] + (h + 0*t + t)*Sin[θ] <= r <= 
    t*Cos[θ] + (h + 0 + t)*Sin[θ] && θ > 0 && 
   r >= 0 && θ < Pi/2, 
  Simplify[-(Integrate[(z00 + z11*x + z22*y)*(x*Cos[θ] + 
           y*Sin[θ] - 
           r), {x, (r/Sin[θ] - h - t)/(k + 1/Tan[θ]), 
         1}, {y, -x/Tan[θ] + r/Sin[θ], 
         k*(r/Sin[θ] - h - t)/(k + 1/Tan[θ]) + h + t}, 
        PrincipalValue -> True] + 
       Integrate[(z00 + z11*x + z22*y)*(x*Cos[θ] + 
           y*Sin[θ] - 
           r), {x, (r/Sin[θ] - h - t)/(k + 1/Tan[θ]), 
         1}, {y, k*(r/Sin[θ] - h - t)/(k + 1/Tan[θ]) + 
          h + t, k*x + h + t}, PrincipalValue -> True]) + (Integrate[
       Cos[θ] + y*Sin[θ] - 
        r, {y, -1/Tan[θ] + r/Sin[θ], h + k + t}] + 
      Integrate[
       x*Cos[θ] + (k*x + h + t)*Sin[θ] - 
        r, {x, (r/Sin[θ] - h - t)/(k + 1/Tan[θ]), 1}])]]
```

where $z_{00},z_{11}$ and $z_{22}$ are undefined constants. The problem I am having is that it returns complex values , but if I do each integral separately namely that of $x,y,x^2,y^2$ it returns real values . Does anyone have a solution for this other than to just use the additive property of the integral ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know.  It took a long time to run, and you didn't warn me, so I just gave up.  Sorry.